# PHP salesforce/handlebars: are JS-style hashless non-block helpers supported?

Tags: php, salesforce, handlebars.js

[salesforce/handlebars](https://github.com/salesforce/handlebars-php) is a PHP parser and renderer for [Javascript Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/) templating. The latter provides two kind of helpers, roughly:

```
{{#block}}
helper, that receives and can manipulate this block and any {{variable}} inside.
The tag starts with a hash, it has opening and closing tags
{{/block}}
```

and

```
{{nonblockhelper usethis}}
```

Now, in PHP Handlebars, just like in Javascript, I can register a block helper such as "bold", to return the enclosed block between `<strong>` tags:

```
{{#bold record.type}}
This text is bold, but only if record.type is "error".
{{/bold}}
```

To make a **non-block** helper called "checked"  that adds the checked property to a checkbox, so that

```
<input name="acheckbox" {{checked record.acheckbox}} />
```

may be rendered, when `record = { acheckbox: true }`, like

```
<input name="acheckbox" checked="checked" />
```

the Javascript helper is readily available and works as expected.

I have not been able to find how to register a similar helper in PHP salesforce/handlebars.

There is a reference to "inline" helpers in the docs, with this example

```
{{#upper title}}
```

that is, however, **not compatible** with Javascript handlebars (I tried; it throws a syntax error, since it doesn't find the /upper closing tag that it expects).

This seems strange to me, as nonblock helpers are pretty popular. On the other hand, maybe very few people require *the same templates* to work both in PHP and Javascript, as unfortunately it looks like I do.

I *could* make do with a block helper, which works both in Javascript and PHP:

```
{{#makechecked record.acheckbox}}
<input name="acheckbox" />
{{/makechecked}}
```

...but it seems awkward, and wasteful. It *is* my plan C, but I think there *should* be some way of getting inline helper support.

So my question is -- ***is* there?**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there are not.

On the other hand, the syntax for a `{{nonblock helper}}` is very similar to that for a `{{variable}}`.

So in `Handlebars/Template.php`, in

```
private function variables
```

I can add my own simple nonblock helper logic.

```
private function variables(Context $context, $current, $escaped) {
    $name  = $current[Tokenizer::NAME];
    $value = $context->get($name);

    // If @data variables are enabled, use the more complex algorithm for handling the the variables otherwise
    // use the previous version.
    if ($this->handlebars->isDataVariablesEnabled()) {
        if (substr(trim($name), 0, 1) == '@') {
            $variable = $context->getDataVariable($name);
            if (is_bool($variable)) {
                return $variable ? 'true' : 'false';
            }
            return $variable;
        }
    } else {
        // If @data variables are not enabled, then revert back to legacy behavior
        if ($name == '@index') {
            return $context->lastIndex();
        }
        if ($name == '@key') {
            return $context->lastKey();
        }
    }

    /* LS20211101 */
    /* Check for non-block helpers {{{ */
    // "Arguments" are subjected to a VERY simple parsing, with NO
    // syntax check. Just simple variables (plus @index and @key)
    // and strings between double quotes, parsed through
    // dirty base64 glomping.

    $words = preg_split('#\\s+#', $name, 2, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $code  = $words[0];
    if ($this->handlebars->hasHelper($code)) {
        $return = call_user_func_array(
            $this->handlebars->getHelper($words[0]),
            [
                $this,      // First argument is this template
                $context,   // Second is current context
                implode(
                    ' ',
                    array_map(
                        function ($token) use ($context) {
                            if ('"' === substr($token, 0, 1)) {
                                return base64_decode($token);
                            }
                            // If @data variables are not enabled, then revert back to legacy behavior
                            if ($token == '@index') {
                                return $context->lastIndex();
                            }
                            if ($token == '@key') {
                                return $context->lastKey();
                            }
                            return $context->get($token);
                        },
                        preg_split(
                            '#\\s+#',
                            preg_replace_callback(
                                '#"([^"]*)"#',
                                function ($matches) {
                                    return '"' . base64_encode($matches[1]) . '"';
                                },
                                $words[1]
                            ),
                            -1,
                            PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY
                        )
                    )
                ),      // Arguments
                ''
            ]);
        if ($return instanceof String) {
            return $this->handlebars->loadString($return)->render($context);
        }
        return $return;
    }
    /** }}} end */

    if ($escaped) {
```